# Angles in an inscribed triangle with one side as diameter, in absolute geometry

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

Let points $A, B$ and $C$ be on a circle $O$ such that segment $AB$ is a diameter of $O$ (meaning the center of the circle is the midpoint of the segment). Prove $m∠C = \frac{1}{2}$ (Internal angle sum(Δ$ABC$)).

Now this is not in Euclidean geometry and it is in neutral geometry. I don't know how to prove it and plus I'm limited since I haven't proven that the sum of the angles in a triangle add up to $180$ and the exterior angle inequality where the angle outside a triangle adds up to the two interior angles. Instead all I have is the Sacceri Legendre theorem (all angles of a triangle add up less than $180^{\circ}$ and exterior angles (angle on the outside is greater than either interior angles). I can use everything else.

Here is a picture:

[image: Triangle]

Comment: "Neutral geometry" is simply Euclidean geometry but without the parallel postulate. Is this correct?

Comment: No but its the same as absolute geometry. But im also limited since i can't use the the theorem that says angles in a triangle add up to 180 or the exterior angle theorem.

Comment: According to Wikipedia "Neutral geometry" is another name for "absolute geometry".

Comment: yes. Now how would i go about it? I tried drawing a tangent line through point c and a line from point c to the center R. But thats as far as i got.

Comment: One minute "no", next minute "yes".

Comment: sorry. Yes neutral geometry is the same as absolute geometry.

Answer (score 2):

Draw the line from the center of the circle to $C$.  The two triangles are isoceles, so $m \angle C = m \angle A + m \angle B$

Comment: how would they be isosceles? Since C looks like lines up with point R that doesn't mean its isosceles.

Comment: @user60887: $A, B,C$ are on the circle, so look at radii.

Comment: ok here is what i have so far  http://i1091.photobucket.com/albums/i383/bonfire091/circle-1.jpg

Comment: Now $\angle RAC =\angle RCA$

Comment: I dont see it unless I can prove AC=BC then it doesn't fit the isoceles triangle theorem which states In triangle ABC if line segment AB is congruent to line segment AC iff angle B is congruent to angle C.

Comment: @user60887:  You need not have $AC=BC$.  You have $RA=RC=RB$ to make the isosceles triangles $RAC$ and $RBC$

Comment: oh i see. Now I just have to get angle C in order.

Comment: now im stuck. I drew a tangent line but I don't see what I can do with it.

Comment: I got it nevermind.